# Is there a way of specifying "wildcards" in externs for Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I recently found Closure Compiler obfuscating HTML `data-` attribute references, e.g. `element.dataset.tests` becomes `r.dataset.a`. Obviously this breaks the script.

This was raised recently as a bug, but was rejected as such: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/3099.

I'm aware I can use the quoted syntax, `element.dataset['tests']`, but this feels a bit wonky. I would like to use externs, since that seems like the best solution, but the problem is it seems I would have to specify each possible key that might be used in the dataset object.

I currently have this:

```
/**
 * @type {DOMStringMap}
 * @const
 */
HTMLElement.prototype.dataset;

/**
 * @type {String}
 * @const
 */
HTMLElement.prototype.dataset.tests;
```

This works fine for this specific script, but it would be more useful just to specify a wildcard that would match any key within any dataset object, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @type {String}
 * @const
 */
HTMLElement.prototype.dataset.*;
```

Does this syntax already exist? Or is there a different way to accomplish this? Essentially I want closure compiler not to apply any advanced optimisations to `element.dataset` or any of its descendants.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "wonky".  I believe you will find the compiler minifies the .dataset['tests'] as .dataset.tests.  If, for some strange reason, it found that leaving it as dataset['tests'] better met its goals of efficiency and brevity, it would probably convert .dataset.tests to .dataset['tests'].

If you do define the attributes in the extern file, spelling out the possibilities gives you an opportunity to document them and what they are used for - and will catch spelling mistakes in the code (which "*", if it worked, wouldn't necessarily do).

Or use jQuery (still has quotes, but won't look as wonky:-)

Comment: I went with wonky. Weird thing is, only seems to do this with `tests`. Doesn't do it on any other `data-` attribute. I would use jQuery, but I despise it :D

Comment: I tried to stay a purist, but just got tired of typing :-)  How about some [love (or at least like)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for the answer?

Comment: It's a little off topic, but since you aren't a fan of wonky, wanted to make sure you had read [this](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/@struct-and-@dict-Annotations) (probably not helpful for dataset).